# Canvas image cannot show all and is clipped can only show part of the image

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, show

I got the image shown but can only show part of the image. I'm wondering if there is any way to show the image as a whole!

```
 var canvas=document.getElementById("Mat_canvas");
canvas.addEventListener('keydown',doKeyDown,true);
var canvt=canvas.getContext("2d");
var img_obj=new Image();
img_obj.onload=function(){
  //canvt.align='center';
  canvt.drawImage(img_obj,0,0);
};
```

Comment: Is your canvas element smaller than the image?

Comment: Is this not JavaScript rather than HTML5?

Comment: @ Skwal,yes it's smaller than the image, I want to see a miniature version though

Comment: @TylerH,yes, I just want to want to make sure that every part works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resize your canvas in the image onload callback:

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("Mat_canvas");
canvas.addEventListener('keydown',doKeyDown,true);
var canvt=canvas.getContext("2d");
var img_obj=new Image();
img_obj.onload=function(){
  //canvt.align='center';

  // resize the canvas to the same size as the source image
  canvas.width=img_obj.width;
  canvas.height=img_obj.height;

  canvt.drawImage(img_obj,0,0);
};
```